# CSS: Store font icon code in css variables

Tags: css

I have a custom icon font (generated with Icomoon).

```
body {
    --pseudo-element-content: '\e900';

    div::before {
     font-family: 'CustomFont';
     content: var(--pseudo-element-content);
    }
}
```

However, when doing this, my pseudo element doesn't appear in my browser (as if it didn't have any content). It looks like my css variable has the icon value interpreted and not its code.

If I change it to

```
div::before {
     font-family: 'CustomFont';
     content: '\e900';
}
```

it works like a charm. I tried a few tricks (string concat, adding `'` and escaping them) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it and it work with another character (see the snippet).

It seems that you don't have that font on your OS and the browser can't render it.

```css
body {
  --pseudo-element-content: "\016E";
}


div::before {
  font-family: "CustomFont";
  content: var(--pseudo-element-content);
}
```

```html
<div>&lt;-- </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

CSS variables are placed in the rules, not at the top level:

```
selector {
  padding: 100px;
  --some-var: 'abcdef'
}
```

Variables are inherited like the ordinary CSS rules.
If you want the variable to be visible everywhere, add it to `html` (or `:root`):

```
html {
  --pseudo-element-content: '\e900';
}
```

**Answer to edited question:**
You are trying to place the styles inside each over, which is not supported in CSS. Perhaps, originally code was for CSS preprocessor - SASS.
The fix:

```css
body {
  --pseudo-element-content: '\e900';
}

div::before {
  font-family: 'CustomFont';
  content: var(--pseudo-element-content);
}
```

Comment: Obviously my css variable was in a rule. I just removed it when simplifying the exemple, I added it back now

Comment: Your CSS is invalid :(
You cannot nest your styles in normal CSS. Perhaps, you should move `div::before` style out from `body`